# Generic log for application crash C++/MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

We have a problem for which I am looking for a direction. We have an old MFC based application, and due to various reasons, the application is crashing sometimes intermittently in some weird scenarios. And even the customers who are using our application and getting these crashes are finding difficulty in identifying the pattern of crash. So, I had a thought that, if we can have a mechanism by which we can generate a log whenever the application crashes. Like for example, the call stack or any other information in that log. I know,, we can use the crash dump in this case, but then I feel like having a log is a better option. So any help or information in this regard would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: so what is your question again ?

Comment: I was looking for some kind of built-in crash logger which I can ship along with my application so that whenever the application crashes, I should be able to use that log and see where the code is broken...

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good implementation of crash reporter in the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5257/XCrashReport-Exception-Handling-and-Crash-Reportin).

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your release build, make sure that both `DEBUG` and [/MAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2%28VS.80%29.aspx) are enabled. Store your binaries together with your `.map` files and let your customer run this version until a crash is produced. In the Event Viewer you will then find a crash log with a *crash offset*. Then debug step into your code (F10) and use the *crash offset* together with some [nifty tricks](http://home.hiwaay.net/~georgech/WhitePapers/MapFiles/MapFiles.htm) and [tricks](http://www.shcherbyna.com/?p=1234) to jump (set the `EIP` register to... well, you have to google this a bit) to the location where the crash occurred. You should now be able to find the error!